# How to configure Apache's Xalan-Transformer to not create empty lines?

Tags: java, xml, whitespace, xalan

I use a Xalan transformer to format xml files with indentation. However, when I apply the formatter to an xml file that already contains indentation, it creates lots of empty lines.

E.g. the input

```
<foo><bar/></foo>
```

is transformed to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>
    <bar/>
</foo>
```

(which I'd consider correct), but applying the transformer to this yields

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><foo>
        
    <bar/>
    
</foo>
```

and successive transformations add ever more empty lines.

I do not remember this behaviour from Saxon transformers. How can I setup my Xalan transformer to not create empty lines?

To be more concrete, here is a simple test encoding the example from above, which I would like to pass with a suitably configured transformer:

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TransformerTest {
    @Test
    void formattingShouldBeIdempotent() throws Exception
    {
      TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newDefaultInstance();
      Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
      transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");

      String transformed1 = transform("<foo><bar/></foo>", transformer);
      String transformed2 = transform(transformed1, transformer);

      Assert.assertEquals(transformed1, transformed2);
    }

    private String transform(String input, Transformer transformer) throws TransformerException
    {
      Source source = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));
      StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
      StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
      transformer.transform(source, result);
      return outWriter.getBuffer().toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try to use XSLT for the XML transformation, It has all the features to control the output XML.

Comment: Thanks. I was focused on solutions setting properties, because the current behaviour seems to me to never be intended. But if an additional transformation (as described in the duplicated issue) is the intended way, I can work with it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use Xalan rather than Saxon, I would suggest preceding the serialization with a simple transformation that essentially just does `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` and then copies the input unchanged.